# Is there a way to import an image from excel to a PictureBox?

Tags: gembox-spreadsheet

I am writing an application that works with Excel files. So far I have been using Gembox spreadsheet to work with excel files. However, I discovered using Gembox spreadsheet I can save pics to excel files, but not retrieve them. Anyone can recommend how to retrieve a pic from excel file? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can retrieve an image from an Excel file with GemBox.Spreadsheet:

```cs
ExcelFile workbook = ExcelFile.Load("Sample.xlsx");
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;

// Select Picture element.
ExcelPicture picture = worksheet.Pictures[0];

// Import to PictureBox control.
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(picture.PictureStream);

// Or write to file.
File.WriteAllBytes("Sample.png", picture.PictureStream.ToArray());
```